# Start a ScheduledExecutorService from a function

Tags: android, multithreading

This works beautifully in `onCreate()`

```
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Calculate_Run();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tv_inseconds.setText(timer_seconds);
                        tv_inminutes.setText(timer_minutes);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

How do I call this from a function? I want to start this thread when the user presses a button.

Comment: Um, copy the code into the method that you want it in. Since `ScheduledExecutorService` is not tied to Android, it is not tied to `onCreate()`. What is your specific problem? BTW, it would be cheaper to just use `postDelayed()`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/260093b033cde1d939d73a77b9b3b7b6a07d19d7/Threads/PostDelayed

Comment: Yeah, I just put it in a method as  private void `startTimer() { code above }`. Sleeping helps :)